# Functors don’t work with data types that require specific types

Tags: haskell

This works fine:

```
data Foo a = Foo a

instance Functor Foo where
  fmap f (Foo s) = Foo (f s)
```

This throws an Error:

```
data Foo = Foo String

instance Functor Foo where
  fmap f (Foo s) = Foo (f s)
```

Error:

```
Kind mis-match
    The first argument of `Functor' should have kind `* -> *',
    but `Foo' has kind `*'
    In the instance declaration for `Functor Foo'
```

What am I missing here? Why can’t I use functors to wrap and unwrap `Foo` if it holds a specific type?

---

**UPDATE**

I guess I can ask this another way:

```
 data Foo = Foo String deriving(Show)

 let jack = Foo "Jack"

 -- Some functory thingy here

 putStrLn $ show $ tail <$> jack
 -- Foo "ack"
```

Why can't I do this? Or is there another construct for this use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of `fmap` is generic; you can't constrain it:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Those `a`s and `b`s *must* be completely polymorphic (within the constraints of your `Functor` instance), or you don't have a `Functor`. The handwavy way of explaining why this is is because a `Functor` must obey some theoretical laws to make them play nice with Haskell's other data types:

```
fmap id = id
fmap (p . q) = (fmap p) . (fmap q)
```

If you have a data type that is parameterized over multiple types, i.e:

```
data Bar a b = Bar a b
```

You can write a `Functor` instance for `Bar a`:

```
instance Functor (Bar a) where
   fmap f (Bar a b) = Bar a (f b)
```

You can also write a [`Bifunctor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-3.2.0.1/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html) instance for `Bar`:

```
instance Bifunctor Foo where
  first  f (Bar a b) = Bar (f a) b
  second f (Bar a b) = Bar a (f b)
```

...which again must follow some laws (listed on the linked page).

Edit:

You could write your own class to handle the type of behavior you're looking for, but it would look like this:

```
class FooFunctor f where
  ffmap :: (String -> String) -> f -> f
```

But in this case, we'd have to make new entire classes for every single permutation of "inner types" we might have (like String), in order to cover all bases.

You can also write a class (call it `Endo`) that only permits endomorphisms (functions of type `a -> a`) on the "inner type" of a data type, like this:

```
class Endo f where
  emap :: (a -> a) -> f a -> f a
```

Then, if you changed your data type a bit, and instantiated an appropriate instance of Endo, e.g.

```
data Foo' a = Foo' a 
type Foo = Foo' String

instance Endo Foo' where
  emap f (Foo a) = Foo (f a)
```

...if you write functions of type `Foo -> Foo`, you're guaranteed to preserve the "Stringiness" of the inner type you're mapping if you use `emap`. A quick search on [hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html#0:%28a%20-%3E%20a%29%20-%3E%20f%20a%20-%3E%20f%20a) reveals that this type of thing is relatively common practice, but doesn't really exist as a standard type class.

Comment: Could you explain why such theoretical laws constrain things so? For example, couldn't you look at (endo)functors on a non-full subcategory by constraining what sorts of functions `fmap` can be applied to? I'm *far* from knowledgable about such matters.

Comment: @dfeuer I'm not a category theorist by any means, so unfortunately I can't answer this question knowledgeably (sorry)! Fortunately, there's a wiki page dedicated to this type of question, so it's possible you'll find what you're looking for there: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory#Functors

Answer (score 10):

That's because `Foo` needs a single type variable to operate on.

The type of `fmap` is:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Now try to specialize this for your `Foo`:

```
(a -> b) -> Foo -> Foo
```

Can you see where the problem is ? The types won't just match. So, to make `Foo` a functor, it has to be something like this:

```
Foo a
```

so that when you specialize it for fmap it has the following proper type:

```
(a -> b) -> Foo a -> Foo b
```

Comment: It still does not make sense to me. What if I have a type `Foo a c`? Do functors only apply to types the hold a maximum of one thing?

Comment: In that case `fmap` will be like this `(a -> b) -> Foo k a -> Foo k b`.

Comment: so no? I need to write a new type if map with that type?

Comment: I think this answer could do with an example usage of Functor that would not work for Foo as defined, for example `fmap length (Foo "Hello")`. On any real functor (say, a `Tree String`), that can count each string, but on Foo it's a type error because you can't construct `Foo 5`: Foo only holds strings!

Comment: @Fresheyeball Type constructors like `Foo` are curried like functions and can be partially applied like functions can. That means `Foo a c` is the same as `(Foo a) c`. You could (potentially) make a `Functor` instance for `(Foo a)`. In this case, `(Foo a)` is a type constructor that takes a type as an argument and gives a type as a result. This means it has a "kind" of `* -> *`. This is exactly the kind something needs in order to be an instance of `Functor`. A kind is to a type what a type is to a value.

Comment: @Fresheyeball You cannot do that for the same reason mentioned by me in the answer. It needs a single type variable to operate on.

Answer (score 4):

Coming from a dynamic language you probably see a Functor as a *container* of stuff and `fmap` as a way to transform things inside the container. However in Category theory a Functor can be seen as a way to transform a type into another type, and a way to transform a function on those type to function on the other type.

Imagine you have 2 differents worlds, one which is earth, and a virtual one when every body/things on earth has an avatar. The Functor is not the avatar but the magic wand which transforms everything to its avatar but also every single function of the real world into a function in the avatar world.

For example, with my magic wand I can transform a human to a frog (or a String to a list of Strings) but I can also transform the function "change the human hat" to change the frog hat" (or capitaize a String to capitalize all the String within a list).

`fmap` is the way you transform a function to another : you can see it as

- a function which take 2 arguments - a function and a container  - and  apply this function to each element of this container
- but also as  a function which take 1 argmunt - a function - an return a function which takes a container and return a container.

The way you create a type from a type is less obvious In your first example you probably just see `Foo String` as new type, but you can also see `Foo` as a super function whic take the type `String` and return a new type : `Foo String`. That's what the `* -> * kind` is. Foo is not a type but a super function creating type from a type.

In your second example, `Foo` is not a type creator but just a simple type (kind : `*`), therefore it doesn't make sense to declare it as a functor.

If you really want to define `fmap` for the plain `Foo` in your 2nd example is to define a real functor and create a type alias for the plain type

```
data FooFunctor a = FooFunctor a
instance Functor Foofunctor where
   fmap f (FooFunctor a) = FooFunctor (f a)


type Foo = FooFunctor String
```

Comment: Ok. Is it at all reasonable to create a type just to be able to fmap over another type (like in your example)?

Comment: Are there existing types out there like `FooFunctor`?

Comment: +1 I am still not quite getting why this is necessary. Question updated.

Comment: @Fresheyeball, yes, it does make sense to create a type "just" to be able to fmap over another type. In general, that new type is likely to be useful in some other context as well. We generalize from `data IntList = IntCons Int IntList | IntNil` to `data [a] = [] | (a:[a])` because that way we can talk about lists of all sorts of things without having to rewrite a bunch of boilerplate. The same goes for functors, and (more complicatedly) monads.

Comment: @Fresheyeball `FooFunctor` is just `Identity`, see https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.2.2.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html

Answer (score 3):

A class that does pretty much exactly what you're asking for is [MonoFunctor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-0.6.0.4/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoFunctor).

```
type instance Element Foo = String

instance MonoFunctor Foo where
  fmap f (Foo s) = Foo (f s)
```

Answer (score 3):

`head "Jack"` is not the string `"J"`, but the character `'J'`. So your own example shows why this does not work; `head <$> jack` would have to give `Foo 'J'`, which is not a valid value of type `Foo`, since `Foo` can only be applied to `String` values, not `Char` values.

"Some other construct" for this use case is to define a "map" function for `Foo`, exactly as you're trying to define fmap. But that map function is ***not*** fmap, since it has to have type `(String -> String) -> Foo -> Foo`. So there's no need (or possibility) to make `Foo` an instance of `Functor` and name your mapping function `fmap`; the mapping function you want to use is simply not fmap.

Note that this means you *cannot* map arbitrary functions over your `Foo` values; only functions which take and return strings (so `head` is still out). Nor can you pass `Foo` values to generic functions that accept values in any functor; those functions might try to `fmap` functions over `Foo` that do not return strings; they're allowed to do this because they specified that they need *functors*, and that's exactly what defines a functor.